# mask not applied to SVG <rect>

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to apply a stripe pattern to `<rect>` elements in my html, but it looks like the pattern is not getting applied.

```css
.green-class {
  fill: green;
  height: 40px;
  mask: url(#mask-stripe) !important
}
```

```html
<svg class="availability-time-line-graphic" id="uptime-component-dbl6mg39xr0j" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="34" viewBox="150 0 298 34"><defs>
        <pattern id="pattern-stripe" width="4" height="4" patternunits="userSpaceOnUse" patterntransform="rotate(45)">
          <rect width="2" height="4" transform="translate(0,0)" fill="white"></rect>
        </pattern>
        <mask id="mask-stripe">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-stripe)">
        </rect></mask>      
        </defs>
        <rect height="34" width="3" x="440" y="0" fill="#2fcc66" class="uptime-day component-dbl6mg39xr0j day-88 green-class" data-html="true"></rect>
        <rect height="34" width="3" x="445" y="0" fill="#2fcc66" class="uptime-day component-dbl6mg39xr0j day-89 green-class" data-html="true"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: That explains it, Is there a way to apply the mask if it's in a different file?

Comment: Even if I directly add the ```fill="url(#mask-stripe)"``` in the rect tags, it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to control the pattern if you set the viewBox attribute on `<pattern>`.

I also changed the viewBox on `<svg>` and the position and size of the `<rect>`. It wasn't clear what you would like to achieve.

```css
.green-class {
  fill: green;
  mask: url(#mask-stripe) !important;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern-stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="10" height="10" patterntransform="rotate(45)">
      <rect width="10" height="20" fill="white"/>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask-stripe">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-stripe)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect height="50" width="50" class="green-class"/>
</svg>
```